# OSX Eclipse CDT - root style includes

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

In a C++ project, in Eclipse CDT, one point of contention that I often have is the pain of removal a file because of the way it handles includes. In Xcode, it is possible to use the file name, or name relative from the project directory however eclipse requires me to often have backwards ".." relative paths which can be difficult to read, track as the project grows in complexity.

Includes currently look like this:

```
`../../model/geometry/Square.h`
```

Ideally i'd like to have all includes, pretend they are being called from the 'root of src directory' such as

```
`model/geometry/Square.h`
```

I understand that includes are essentially a preprocessor, find-replace instruction however this is 2012, there must be a way.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is a way of doing so :

Right click on your **Project -> Properties -> Open the C/C++ General tab -> Path and Symbols -> select your language on the left (C++/C/Assembly) -> on the right, click on Add...** And select your folder location!

Hope it helped!

*Edit:
Remember that if you include a folder, you can then include the files which are in that particular folder directly*

```
#include "file.h" and not #include "folderIncluded/file.h"
```

Regards,
Erwald

Comment: So just place the variable, "${ProjDirPath}/src" ?... So the compiler and the indexer will be able to find this, be happy and also provide autocompletion?

Comment: Yup, normally it should work (tried it myself earlier which is the reason for the "edit" on the post) and it worked like a charm! Let me know if you have any problem!

Comment: Ok I will test tomorrow, but im sure it will work. I'll mark your answer after I try :) - thx